# Plot yerr/xerr as shaded region rather than error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, how do I plot error as a shaded region rather than error bars?

For example:

[image]

rather than

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting shaded uncertainty region in line plot in matplotlib when data has NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064524/plotting-shaded-uncertainty-region-in-line-plot-in-matplotlib-when-data-has-nans)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Ignoring the smooth interpolation between points in your example graph (that would  require doing some manual interpolation, or just have a higher resolution of your data), you can use [`pyplot.fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
y = np.sin(x/6*np.pi)
error = np.random.normal(0.1, 0.02, size=y.shape)
y += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=y.shape)

plt.plot(x, y, 'k-')
plt.fill_between(x, y-error, y+error)
plt.show()
```

[image]

See also the [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

Comment: Perfect. Yeah I didn't mean to include an example with smoothed lines.

Comment: Any idea how to make this show shaded boxes instead of a shaded band? My first instinct was to abuse `lw` but it appears to not use the same units as the axes.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I'm not fully sure what you mean. It sounds as if you'd like a box drawn at each point, its height the same as that of the error bar, while the width should be such that they connect (touch) the neighbouring boxes. Is that correct?

Comment: Is there a way to combine the blue fill_between and the black plot as one entry in the legend?

Comment: @EL_DON You mean you'd like a legend with a black line + blue band, and the text would be something like "data + 1 sigma error region"?

Comment: @Evert Yes, exactly.

Comment: What if errorbars are horizontal? I don't seem to know a way of doing it. Any idea?

Comment: @Allan if the only error bars you have are horizontal, you probably should flip the axes of your actual problem (and thus the figure as well). Normally, the independent variable is the one without (or with very small) error bars. You may be able to cheat, by swapping your data variables, and in matplotlib, swap the axes as well.

Comment: You can create a customized function that “interpolates” (x, y) points via numpy functions (linspace or tile or extending slices) inbetween your actual (x, y) data; apply the function iteratively, switching from moving iterating across x and y per iteration, and concatenate all the x and y data in the correct order. This way, plt.fill_between(...) will feel in such a way that the shaded region will appear as n boxes instead of a shaded band. The shorter the spacing between points along an axis, the boxier the filled region will appear.

Comment: I think this answer would have more value if - instead of making an `error` and adding it to `y` - add some random noise to `y` and calculate quartiles. This is what (IMO) most people coming to this question are actually interested in.

Answer (score 160):

This is basically the [same answer provided by Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958534/17523), but extended to show-off
some cool options of `fill_between`

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

pl.clf()
pl.hold(1)

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 100)
y = np.sin(x) * 0.5
pl.plot(x, y, '-k')


x = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
y = np.sin(x/6*np.pi)
error = np.random.normal(0.1, 0.02, size=y.shape) +.1
y += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=y.shape)

pl.plot(x, y, 'k', color='#CC4F1B')
pl.fill_between(x, y-error, y+error,
    alpha=0.5, edgecolor='#CC4F1B', facecolor='#FF9848')

y = np.cos(x/6*np.pi)    
error = np.random.rand(len(y)) * 0.5
y += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=y.shape)
pl.plot(x, y, 'k', color='#1B2ACC')
pl.fill_between(x, y-error, y+error,
    alpha=0.2, edgecolor='#1B2ACC', facecolor='#089FFF',
    linewidth=4, linestyle='dashdot', antialiased=True)



y = np.cos(x/6*np.pi)  + np.sin(x/3*np.pi)  
error = np.random.rand(len(y)) * 0.5
y += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=y.shape)
pl.plot(x, y, 'k', color='#3F7F4C')
pl.fill_between(x, y-error, y+error,
    alpha=1, edgecolor='#3F7F4C', facecolor='#7EFF99',
    linewidth=0)



pl.show()
```

Comment: Slightly better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064524/plotting-shaded-uncertainty-region-in-line-plot-in-matplotlib-when-data-has-nans