# Shaded uncertainty/error region in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, uncertainty

I'm searching for a way to draw shaded error-regions instead of error-bars in Python.

I know that there is [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) with which you can build a workaround for the y-error but that does not include the x-uncertainty.

[image: problem_description]

Any ideas? Unfortunately I had not enough reputation to put a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13157955/3383640).

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**

`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx()` leads to something like:

[image: fill_between_problem1]

---

**Edit 2**

Furthermore I suppose it to be incorrect for a complete uncertainty area. Below I draw what I suppose to be the correct shape - I hope, I'm not wrong here...

[image: problem_sketch]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
y = np.asarray([1.0, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0])
xerr = np.asarray([0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1])
yerr = np.asarray([0.1, 0.9, 1.2, 0.1])

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr)

plt.fill_between(x, y-yerr, y+yerr, facecolor='#F0F8FF', alpha=1.0, edgecolor='none')
plt.fill_betweenx(y,x-xerr, x+xerr, facecolor='#F0F8FF', alpha=1.0, edgecolor='#8F94CC', linewidth=1, linestyle='dashed')

plt.show()
# Red lines added with inkscape.
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, too. However, don't you think that that's a rather conservative estimate? I'll try to figure out a smart way for fitting a bounding curve to a point cloud. What's your deadline?

Comment: I adjusted the sketch a bit to
 
i)  be more clear and 
ii) to correct some mistakes.

I don't think that my example is conservative. Imagine completely uncorrelated points with error-values (wherever they come from). You therefore have to consider square error-regions. How does the error propagate between two points? The simplest approach would be the first-order approximation that I sketched. Don't put too many effort in that! Python has sooo incredible many modules, I can not imagine that there is nothing for such a very basic problem.

Answer (score 11):

I got this to work with the `fill_betweenx` function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
y = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
xerr = np.asarray([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
yerr = np.asarray([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr)

plt.fill_between(x, y-yerr, y+yerr,facecolor='r',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_betweenx(y,x-xerr,x+xerr,facecolor='b',alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Which results in this plot:

[image: fill_between, fill_betweenx]

---

**EDIT**

In your specific example, it may be sufficient to use:

```
plt.fill_between(x, y-yerr, y+yerr,facecolor='#F0F8FF',alpha=1.0,edgecolor='none')
plt.fill_betweenx(y,x-xerr, x+xerr,facecolor='#F0F8FF',alpha=1.0,edgecolor='none')
```

That way, you do not have edges, which would cross and give this "fold" away. Furthermore, it might generate a sufficient illusion of one error band. You'd have to use both the `fill_between` and `fill_betweenx`, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I see difficulties putting xerr and yerr to one uncertainty-area (same color) with borders (`edgecolor`). This would still lead to interferences.

Comment: Added a picture in the post. You can see the intersections in the upper part.

Comment: @smoneck Do I understand correctly: You are looking for one envelope, that includes all the errors in a smooth band? Or, for example in your plot for an Anstellwinkel = 0, would you like the band to touch the `y`-error? or is that part of the plot like you would want it?

Comment: @smoneck I'll investigate this further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, Schorsch! But when I'm right, the uncertainty area is wrong when having overlapping xerr and yerr. I added a drawing of the problem, where I added a red line which complements the area which I suppose to be the correct one.