# Show distribution of data about mean using contours

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction with some functions or code (in python) which would allow me to plot the distribution of a timeseries dataset using contours, as shown in the attached image.

I have a dataset like the one used in this graph, over multiple days. I have created a graph with the mean value at each hour, but I want to properly show the distribution about the mean using percentage frequency, similar to the contour format in the image.

If anyone could link me to some examples on how to do this, it would be a great help, as I have been unable to find anything useful anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Use hist2d for the pcolor below the line.

Comment: Maybe something like [Fanplot from quantiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70909386/fanplot-in-python-from-quantiles/70909994#70909994)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for this! Here's an example:

```python
import seaborn as sns

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri").query("region == 'parietal'")

p = so.Plot(fmri, "timepoint", "signal")
for tail in [25, 10, 5, 1]:
    p = p.add(so.Band(), so.Perc([tail, 100 - tail]))
p.add(so.Line(), so.Agg("median"))
```

Which will result in this plot:

[image: Timeseries distribution plot]

You can read more about it in [Statistical estimation and error bars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars).

I hope this helps!