Plotting exponential trend line
Exponential line that does not fit to along the triangles.
I'm trying to plot the exponential trend line in python. I used following code to plot the exponential trend line. Can anyone help me to point out what is the problem and how I should modify the code to get the curve that fit to the triangles.
input file

I used following code to plot the curve.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager
import pandas as pd
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Load the data
pga_data = pd.read_excel('D:/21_july_2022_kengtung_eq/oq_gmpe_july_22/25_july/oq_output_25_july/compare_sta_PGA_and_gmpes_22_aug_2024.xlsx')

# exponential fitting
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

p0 = [pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'].max(), 1/pga_data['hypo_dist'].mean(), pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'].min()]
popt_exp, _ = curve_fit(func, pga_data['hypo_dist'], pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'], p0=p0, maxfev=2000)
x_fit = np.linspace(pga_data['hypo_dist'].min(), pga_data['hypo_dist'].max(), 1500)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *popt)

# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=500)

# Scatter plot with label for legend
scatter = plt.scatter(pga_data['hypo_dist'], pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'], marker='^', c='skyblue',
                      edgecolors='black', label='SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA')

# Plot curve fitting result
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, linestyle=style, color=color)

# Add legend with title
plt.legend(title="Seismic Networks", title_fontsize=14, loc='upper right', frameon=True, prop=font_manager.FontProperties(family='Times New Roman'))

# Customize legend appearance
legend = plt.gca().get_legend()
legend.get_title().set_fontproperties(font_manager.FontProperties(family='Times New Roman', weight='bold'))
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
legend.get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

# Set scales and limits
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(10, 1500)

# Add labels with font properties
plt.xlabel('Hypocentral Distance (km)', fontname='Times New Roman')
plt.ylabel('PGA (g)', fontname='Times New Roman')

# Add grid
plt.grid(True, which="both", axis="both", color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)

# Set background color to white
plt.gca().set_facecolor('white')

# Set color and width of axis lines
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_linewidth(1)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

May I know how can i also include shaded area around the curve indicating the uncertainty range (±1 standard deviation) like following figure.


Can we have your data to try with?

Hello Lastchance,
Yes, I am having a problem in curve fitting. I apologize for the confusion about the '1' link—it was a mistake and should be disregarded. I've included the input data in my earlier message. Thank you for your assistance!

Note that showing a picture of the input data is nearly useless, unless you expect us to type in all the numbers ourselves.

Hello mkrieger1,
I'm new to this platform and I'm not familiar with how it works. I didn't realize that uploading an Excel file directly wasn't supported, so I mistakenly uploaded a picture instead. I apologize for the confusion and any inconvenience this may have caused.

You almost certainly haven't got enough flexibility in the shape of your curve. I suggest
y = a.exp(-b * x ** n)

You also need a better initial guess p0.
Because of the multi-decadal range in y, you would get a better fit from log(y) against x first; i.e.
log(y) = log(a) - b * x ** n

You can convert back to y(x) by simply recovering a from log(a).
The relevant changed lines are here. (Full code at the bottom.)
# exponential fitting
def func( x, a, b, n):
    return a * np.exp( -b * x ** n )

def funclog( x, loga, b, n):          # this is log(y)
    return loga -b * x ** n

# Fit log(y) against x first
p0 = [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.5 ]
popt, _ = curve_fit(funclog, pga_data['hypo_dist'], np.log( pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'] ), p0=p0, maxfev=2000)

# Then convert back to y(x)
popt[0] = math.exp( popt[0] )

print( "a, b, n =", popt )

Please make sure that you include all the imports etc (like numpy) so that your code will run.

Full code. (Note that I have changed the name of your input file to test.xls)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager
import pandas as pd
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# Load the data
pga_data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# exponential fitting
def func( x, a, b, n):
    return a * np.exp( -b * x ** n )

def funclog( x, loga, b, n):          # this is log(y)
    return loga -b * x ** n

# Fit log(y) against x first
p0 = [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.5 ]
popt, _ = curve_fit(funclog, pga_data['hypo_dist'], np.log( pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'] ), p0=p0, maxfev=2000)

# Then convert back to y(x)
popt[0] = math.exp( popt[0] )

print( "a, b, n =", popt )


x_fit = np.linspace(pga_data['hypo_dist'].min(), pga_data['hypo_dist'].max(), 1500)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *popt)

# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=500)

# Scatter plot with label for legend
scatter = plt.scatter(pga_data['hypo_dist'], pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'], marker='^', c='skyblue',
                      edgecolors='black', label='SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA')

# Plot curve fitting result
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit )

# Add legend with title
plt.legend(title="Seismic Networks", title_fontsize=14, loc='upper right', frameon=True, prop=font_manager.FontProperties(family='Times New Roman'))

# Customize legend appearance
legend = plt.gca().get_legend()
legend.get_title().set_fontproperties(font_manager.FontProperties(family='Times New Roman', weight='bold'))
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
legend.get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

# Set scales and limits
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(10, 1500)

# Add labels with font properties
plt.xlabel('Hypocentral Distance (km)', fontname='Times New Roman')
plt.ylabel('PGA (g)', fontname='Times New Roman')

# Add grid
plt.grid(True, which="both", axis="both", color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)

# Set background color to white
plt.gca().set_facecolor('white')

# Set color and width of axis lines
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_linewidth(1)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_linewidth(1)

# Show the plot
plt.show()


After implementing the suggested code changes, the trendline in the resulting figure is displayed as a horizontal line. I attached the input file to test.
C:\Users\seismolab\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19080\2991112237.py:15: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
popt, _ = curve_fit(func, pga_data['hypo_dist'], pga_data['SiMidorikawa1999Asc_PGA_g'], p0=p0, maxfev=2000)

@Moly, now you have supplied your data we can test it. You merely need a better initial guess p0. My post is updated. Note that, given the multi-decadal ranges of y involved, you might like to consider fitting in log-space first. I have done that in my amended code.

Hello @lastchance Thank you so much for your help and for updating your post! I really appreciate your efforts in assisting me.
May I know how can i also include shaded area around the curve indicating the uncertainty range (±1 standard deviation).

@Moly, you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957582/plot-yerr-xerr-as-shaded-region-rather-than-error-bars
